# Passing a python function as an arg to a function in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, pyqt5

Sorry for the long post but wished to give as much as poss

There is a lot of code not shown here but I'm trying to clean up a huge function of buttons in a PyQt5 Gui

I have a GUI output and all is working well and I'm now making an attempt to remove the repeated code and so creating a function to create the buttons.

In a functioned name initUI I have around 20 buttons. As can be seen from the code, the old way was creating each one separately.

What I have done is to create a function that the parameters are sent to and this then creates them.

This does work apart from defRun arg sent to button.
This is passing a call to another function ***I've highlighted with >>>>arg<<<< this isn't really in the code***

```
class iac2tf(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(iac2tf, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1700, 1000)........

     def button (self, buttonName, buttonText, >>>>defRun<<<<, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, buttonx, buttony):
            self.buttonName = QtWidgets.QPushButton(buttonText,self)
        >>>>self.buttonName.clicked.connect(lambda:self.defRun)<<<<
            self.buttonName.resize(buttonWidth,buttonHeight)
            self.buttonName.move(buttonx,buttony)   
            self.buttonName.show()

    def initUI(self): 
            #passed style
            self.openFilebutton = self.button('openFile', 'Open File', >>>'open()'<<<< ,110,30,5,50)

            #Old style
            self.ProcessFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Process File',self)
            self.ProcessFile.clicked.connect(self.processFile)
            self.ProcessFile.resize(110,30)
            self.ProcessFile.move(5, 80)  


/......
   ....../


def open(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Ope....... 


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = iac2tf()
win.show()
```

***I've tried passing*** Knowing some would fail but wanted to cover all bases and was exasperated

- str(open)

GUI opens with

```
<built-in function open>
```

On clicking button

```
  File "/home/bob/present/proj/WorksArea/gui.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    self.buttonName.clicked.connect(lambda:self.defRun)
AttributeError: 'iac2tf' object has no attribute 'defRun'
```

- str(open())

```
self.openFilebutton = self.button('openFile', 'Open File', str(open()) ,110,30,5,50)
TypeError: Required argument 'file' (pos 1) not found
```

- str(self.open)

GUI opens with

```
<bound method iac2tf.open of <__main__.iac2tf object at 0x7f87e73da948>>
```

On clicking button

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bob/present/proj/WorksArea/gui.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    self.buttonName.clicked.connect(lambda:self.defRun)
AttributeError: 'iac2tf' object has no attribute 'defRun'
```

- str(self.open())

Open file selection menu ie starts open func

- self.open

GUI starts

```
<bound method iac2tf.open of <__main__.iac2tf object at 0x7fdcb2dee948>>
```

On clicking button

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bob/present/proj/WorksArea/gui.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    self.buttonName.clicked.connect(lambda:self.defRun)
AttributeError: 'iac2tf' object has no attribute 'defRun'
```

- 'self.open'
- 'self.open()'
- 'open()'
- 'open'

opens GUI without error

on clicking button

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bob/present/proj/WorksArea/gui.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    self.buttonName.clicked.connect(lambda:self.defRun)
AttributeError: 'iac2tf' object has no attribute 'defRun'
```

- open

opens GUI with

```
   <built-in function open>
```

on clicking button

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bob/present/proj/WorksArea/gui.py", line 38, in <lambda>
    self.buttonName.clicked.connect(lambda:self.defRun)
AttributeError: 'iac2tf' object has no attribute 'defRun'
```

- open()

```
self.openFilebutton = self.button('openFile', 'Open File', open() ,110,30,5,50)
TypeError: Required argument 'file' (pos 1) not found
```

- passing to a local to func var all of above but is as is :(

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Ok thanks, will do tomorrow thx

Comment: try with: `self.buttonName.clicked.connect(defRun)` and `self.openFilebutton = self.button('openFile', 'Open File', self.open, 110,30,5,50)`

Comment: Cheers, will do. Are you thinking lambda tripping up? Could you explain (I'm learning)

Comment: What I indicate is a presumption since the code you provide does not give me the necessary guarantee that it works correctly, so I will expect you to provide the information I have asked you to give more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of passing functions as arguments.

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.create_button('Open', self.open)
        self.create_button('Close', self.close)

    def create_button(self, text, slot):
        btn = QPushButton(text)
        btn.clicked.connect(slot)
        self.vbox.addWidget(btn)

    def open(self):
        QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
```

Also worth noting that the arg `buttonName` is never actually used in this function:

```
def button (self, buttonName, buttonText, >>>>defRun<<<<, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, buttonx, buttony):
    self.buttonName = QtWidgets.QPushButton(buttonText,self)
    . . .
```

That variable only exists in the local scope of the function, and `self.buttonName` refers to another object entirely. That is to say, if you wanted to refer to a button you created where you passed `'openFile'` for the `buttonName` arg, it would not be called `self.openFile`, it would be called literally `self.buttonName`. You could however, use `exec()` to achieve this, although it is generally discouraged.

Comment: Cheers I'll give it a bash. That may be a big issue. I was assuming that the button would be named as openFile

Comment: Just looking through my errors, it actually say buttonName.... Feeling silly now . I wasn't seeing the wood for the trees. As said thanks and ill get to try it and report back